# Convert Panda's dataframe which contains images to HTML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, jupyter

Good afternoon.

I am currently having trouble with Panda's dataframe. Please consider the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import display,HTML

df = pd.DataFrame([['A231', 'Book', 5, 3, 150], 
                   ['M441', 'Magic Staff', 10, 7, 200]],
                   columns = ['Code', 'Name', 'Price', 'Net', 'Sales'])

# your images
images = ['https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/7/7a/Mage%27s_book_detail.png/revision/latest?cb=20180310083825',
          'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d9/5c/9b/d95c9ba809aa9dd4cb519a225af40f2b.png'] 


df['image'] = images

# convert your links to html tags 
def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

display(HTML(df.to_html(escape=False ,formatters=dict(image=path_to_image_html))))
```

Which displays the following:
[image: Result]

How can I import this specific dataframe to a HTML file?

I tried the following code,

```
df.to_html(open('my_file2.html', 'w'))
```

Which works fine, but, "my_file2.html" displays like this:
[image: my_file2.html]
How can I modify the code so that in my_file2.html, in the column "image", it shows the actual image and not the link to the image?

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to html format. so image is picked from source.

```
df1['image']=  '''<img src="''' + df1['image'] + '''">''' 
with open('r.html', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(df1.to_html(render_links=True,escape=False))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @simpleApp, have a great Friday!